# Updating an ongoing Apache Beam / Dataflow job with new Kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We use Dataflow on Google Cloud Platform to ingest messages from Kafka into Google Cloud Storage. The objects uploaded are hourly partitioned and have the following format:

```
gs://output-bucket/topics/<topic>/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=dd/hour=HH/<windowStart>-<windowEnd>-<pane>.<format>
```

There is also the possibility for late data to arrive which would land in additional panes.

The idea was to use one Dataflow job to ingest multiple Kafka topics using [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html). This works fine, however, now and then we also have to add and/or delete topics on our ingestion list and update our job with this information. It is important to not loose any data in the update process (e.g. data  in windows that have not been written out to Cloud Storage) and also keep the information about late data.

The behaviour we wish for is:

1. We add and/or delete topics on our list
2. We update the Dataflow job with the new topics parameter
3. The job keeps ingesting old topics with their current offset and starts ingesting new topics from the earliest offset.

So we tried [updating the existing pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline) by changing the input topics parameter only and get the following error:

```
CESTError message from worker: java.lang.IllegalStateException: checkPointMark and assignedPartitions should match
```

It seems like it can't handle this type of update but we feel there must be a way to achieve our goal.

Question: What is the right way to read multiple Kafka topics with one Dataflow job and be able to update the topics parameter for an existing pipeline?

This is a code snippet of the basic pipeline:

```java
pipeline
        .apply(
            "ReadFromKafka",
            KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                .withBootstrapServers(options.getBootstrapServers())
                .withTopics(parseTopics(options.getInputTopics()))
                .withCreateTime(Duration.standardMinutes(10))
                .withReadCommitted()
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(parseConsumerConfig(options)))
        .apply("CreateWindows", HourlyWindowsWithAllowedLateness.of(Duration.standardDays(7)))
        .apply(
            "WriteFileOutput",
             FileIO.<String, KafkaRecord<String, String>>writeDynamic()
                .by(DestinationFunction.of())
                .via(
                    Contextful.fn(KafkaRecordToGenericRecordFunction.of()),
                    AvroIO.sink(KafkaRecordToGenericRecordFunction.SCHEMA))
                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withTempDirectory(options.getTempDirectory())
                .to(options.getOutputDirectory())
                .withNaming(NamingFunction.avro()));
```

Comment: For your requirement, you can try [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html) class which can be used to read multiple topics.For updating the dataflow pipeline, you can use [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update).Let me know if that helps.

Comment: KafkaIO can read multiple topics, but that doesn't support adding or deleting topics from a running pipeline. My first instinct seeing this requirement is maybe it's possible to have some kind of script that manages starting up new pipelines with updated topics (using Dataflow templates to have the topics as a pipeline option). I.e. when the list changes, shut down the old pipeline and drain it (so it finishes reading what it claimed), while starting a new pipeline with the new set of topics. Maybe Cloud Functions could help?